# Getting NSURL of System Root Directory

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to get the `NSURL` of the root directory. I have tried this:

```
NSURL *rootURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/" isDirectory:YES];
```

but it prints

```
file://localhost/
```

I want my output to be

```
file:///
```

Any help on this simple one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///"];
```

It returns what you want.

Comment: Thanks Bro..It's Working fine for Cocoa as well

Answer (score 0):

`file://localhost/` is valid.. I don't know if `file:///` is also a valid url but if it would be, they are identical.

Comment: I am comparing **rootURL** with a bunch of Url's in a NSArray and that NSArray contains **file:///** which is always skipped in comparison.